# Parameter passed to a component doesn't change thus the data the component should get from the backend doesn't change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Whenever I change the `query` the data of an empty `query` is shown and an empty `query` is passed to the component

I am trying to get it to refresh the data whenever the user searches for a `keyword` so the keyword is now the `query`, but it calls the `AttacksGrid` component with an empty query every time and thus showing the same data every time.
For the first time when the component is created it should have an empty `query` to show all the data by default so I just set the initial value of `query` in the state hook to an empty string.

This is the `app` where I connected everything together.

```js
function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  const searchClicked = (keyword) => {
    console.log(`setting query to: ${keyword}`);
    setQuery(keyword); // for now we want to search for the keyword in the name and description, platform is not supported yet
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar onSearchClicked={searchClicked} />
      <AttacksGrid query={query} />;
    </div>
  );
}
```

And those are the AttacksGrid component which is supposed to be a table that gets the data from the backend corresponding to the `query`

```js
function AttacksGrid({ query }) {
  console.log(`QUERY IS ${query}`);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:9000/attacks?name=${query}&description=${query}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setAttacks(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, [query]);

  const [attacks, setAttacks] = useState([]);

  return (
    <>
      <table className="table table-dark">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Platforms</th>
            <th scope="col">Detection</th>
            <th scope="col">Phase</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        {attacks.map((attack) => (
          <tbody key={attack.ID}>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">{attack.NAME}</th>
              <td>{attack.DESCRIPTION}</td>
              <td>{attack.X_MITRE_PLATFORMS}</td>
              <td>{attack.X_MITRE_DETECTION}</td>
              <td>{attack.PHASE_NAME}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        ))}
      </table>
    </>
  );
}
```

And this is the navbar where you search for a keyword and thus supposed to change the query

```js
function Navbar({ onSearchClicked }) {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setMessage(event.target.value);
    console.log(message);
  };
  return (
    <nav className="navbar bg-body-tertiary">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <form className="d-flex" role="search">
          <input
            id="message"
            name="message"
            className="form-control me-2"
            type="search"
            placeholder="Search"
            aria-label="Search"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <button
            className="btn btn-outline-success"
            type="submit"
            onClick={() => {
              onSearchClicked(message);
            }}
          >
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You form is getting submitted and page is refreshed when you click on submit button. This causes whole app to refresh with its data.

you need to prevent the default action for the form

```
<button
  className="btn btn-outline-success"
  type="submit"
  onClick={(e) => {
   e.preventDefault(); //Preventing default page refresh submit form action
   onSearchClicked(message);
  }}>
  Search
</button>
```